# Keep Angular Dropdown Menu Open After Reload

Tags: javascript, html, sql, angular, typescript

I am operating an HTML/Typescript view that connects to a SQL Database. Any time the SQL is altered, the entire webpage reloads. There are several dropdown menus that clients would like to remain open after these reloads, to avoid time spent reopening, only closing once the button from which the dropdown originates is clicked, or a location outside the menu is clicked. Is there a way to ensure an open dropdown menu remains open after a reload?

Here is an example of one such dropdown.

```
<mat-form-field>
            <mat-label>Month</mat-label>
            <mat-select formControlName="month" (selectionChange)="isStandardOrCurrentCost()">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let month of getAvailableMonths()" [value]="month">{{month}}</mat-option>
            </mat-select>
            <control-messages [control]="form.get('month')"></control-messages>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: I think if you reload the page it is not possible. If you load the select box option by using an HTTP call we can achieve this.

Comment: The select box is loaded through an asynchronous HTTP call within the Typescript; unfortunately, I'm working with a pre-existing framework that must reload the page if a SQL value is altered.

Comment: then we cant keep open the select box after reloading the page.  But when the user opens any select box you can get that select box reference and stored in local storage if the user selects the option you need to remove that reference from local storage. After the page load open the select box by using the local storage reference.

Comment: The page refreshes, the browser tab does not reload. I assume that allows me to keep record of which dropboxes were open in local storage?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an option you can consider is saving the state of opened dropdowns in the local storage. Whenever the page reload, life cycle methods will be called. Using something like ngAfterViewInit or ngAfterContentInit, you can get the state to see which dropdowns are activated. Then simulate a click on your `select` element. Use @ViewChild to get the html element and `.nativeElement.click()` to simulate the click. This is less than optimal and in the best world, you would only reload the component which consumes to SQL data, not the entire page.

Comment: I'll try that! Unfortunately, I'm working in a fairly rigid framework so the entire page must be reloaded.